# After update i got strange error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, mysql, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0

I just updated my Magento to 1.9.2 and there is the error log file:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`value)` = '0') AND (`start_time` = '2015-10-' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `bannerslider_banner` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `bannerslider_value` AS `status` ON main_table.banner_id = status.banner_id AND status.store_id = 1 AND status.attribute_code = 'status' WHERE (`bannerslider_id` = '2') AND (`IF(status`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`status, status`.`value)` = '0') AND (`start_time` = '2015-10-28') ORDER BY order_banner ASC

```
a:5:{i:0;s:643:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`value)` = '0') AND (`start_time` = '2015-10-' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `bannerslider_banner` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `bannerslider_value` AS `status` ON main_table.banner_id = status.banner_id AND status.store_id = 1 AND status.attribute_code = 'status' WHERE (`bannerslider_id` = '2') AND (`IF(status`.`value IS NULL, main_table`.`status, status`.`value)` = '0') AND (`start_time` = '2015-10-28') ORDER BY order_banner ASC";i:1;s:4886:"#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/Block/Default.php(44): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml(28): Magestore_Bannerslider_Block_Default->getBlockData()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#14 app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/Block/Bannerslider.php(47): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Magestore_Bannerslider_Block_Bannerslider->_toHtml()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#20 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/d...')
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#29 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#30 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#31 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#32 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#33 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I can not understand where i can find the file causing the problem.

Can you help me out find the file which is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably is a MySQL injection vulnerability patched away by SUPEE-6788 and will require you to contact the Module developer to get the other half of the patch which is a module upgrade.

Comment: I would discourage to use Magestore modules as their coding quality is really poor. Once again you see that using hardcoded SQL instead of sticking with Magento's ORM solution and PDO style queries is a bad practice.

Answer (score 6):

A (temporary - until the developers release a new version) fix that worked for me:

In file

```
app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php
```

at line 60 comment the following:

```
return parent::addFieldToFilter("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value)", $condition);
```

and replace it with

```
 $this->getSelect()->where("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value) = 0");
```

As per answer found here: http://answers.magentocommerce.com/answers/4643-en_us/product/3912/magestore-banner-slider-questions-answers/questions.htm?sort=recentq#BVQASAnswerText598988

Comment: The query generated in app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php is mangled due to variable escaping after the update. Not the first time we've had problem with bad code from Magestore

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `bannerslider/bannerslider` module is trying to save someting from the CMS page and is having issues saving. When you upgraded make sure you add the `bannerslider/bannerslider` block to the whitelist table.

Comment: Where is that whitelist and how can i add `bannerslider/bannerslider`

Comment: You should be able to see it under `system > permissions > blocks` and adding it there.

Comment: In system - permissions i have only users and roles. I do not have blocks..

Comment: As part of the upgrade to 1.9.2.2 it adds those fields so i suspect the upgrade may not have run

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Fiasco Labs labs comment. This is likely an incompatibility between whatever banner slider extension you have installed and APPSEC-1063. The same issue was reported [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88111/added-block-to-whitelist-but-blocks-still-not-showing-6788) and I went into detail on what is happening and some ideas on how to debug / mitigate other issues that could pop up from APPSEC-1063.

You can try to contact the extension developer, or you could try to patch it yourself.